# foreach key -> value outside foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, custom-fields

How can I access specific 'keys' and their associated 'values' for use later outside of the foreach loop?

Here's the array;

```
Array ( [0] => 
CustomFields 
[1] => stdClass Object  
     ( [Key] => Phone [Value] => 5555555 ) 
[2] => stdClass Object 
     ( [Key] => City [Value] => New York) 
[3] => stdClass Object 
     ( [Key] => State [Value] => NY) 
[4] => stdClass Object 
     ( [Key] => Cellphone [Value] => 222444555 )
```

And here's the query I'm using;

```
$cf = array();
foreach($result->response->CustomFields as $data) {

   $cf [] = $data;

         if ($cf [] = ($data->Key == 'Phone' ) ) {
             echo 'Your Phone number is:'.$data->Value.'<br> ';
         }

          if ($cf [] = ($data->Key == 'City' ) ) {
             echo 'Your City is: '.$data->Value.'<br> ';
         } 
}
```

My query works inside the foreach loop and correctly prints the Phone and City value - but I would like to be able to print these values outside of this loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function findByKeyInCollection($key, $collection){
    foreach($collection as $data) {
         if ($data->Key == $key) {
             return $data;
         }
    }
}
$phone = findByKeyInCollection("Phone", $result->response->CustomFields);
echo 'Your Phone number is:'.$phone->Value.'<br> ';
```

Comment: Wow - thank you - that works perfectly - and you make it look so easy!!  Much appreciated ;-)